# "Action State" vs "State" in UML Activity diagram

Tags: uml

I'm a newbie with UML and Microsoft Visio. 
Today, I have a homework which I need to draw an activity diagram in an UML project. My team use Visio 2003 to draw these diagrams. 
When I open Visio and seek for Activity Diagram I see both Action State and State icon in the left panel, I'm very confused with the difference between them, then I post this question.
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: do you really need to add "homework" tag? I'm doing homework but Im not asking you all to do it for me, I'm asking about UML.

Comment: yes, because if it is a homework, we want to help you to learn how to work with UML, not just give you an answer:)

Comment: @Gabriel, Tanparmaiel : thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [UML 1.4.2 specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/ISO/19501/PDF/) (section 4.13.2.1):

> An action state represents the
>   execution of an atomic action,
>   typically the invocation of an
>   operation.

ActionState has been replaced, as of UML 2.0, by Action. From section 12.3.2 of the [UML 2.0 Superstructure specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.0/Superstructure/PDF/):

> Explicitly modeled actions as part of
>   activities are new in UML 2.0, and
>   replace ActionState, CallState, and
>   SubactivityState in UML 1.5.

Read the 'Activities' section of the UML Superstructure spec for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Every such question about abstract syntax of UML can be answered by looking into the specification.

The official UML specification is released by OMG: http://www.uml.org/#UML2.0

By clicking around you get to the link to actual specification: http://www.omg.org/technology/documents/modeling_spec_catalog.htm#UML

Check out the UML Superstructure document: http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.3/Superstructure/PDF/

Now to your question - the superstructure document is split into parts (the second describes behaviours) and into chapters according to the aspect you are modeling - in your case Activities in chapter 12.

There are several sections - abstract syntax, class descriptions and diagrams. In abstract syntax, you can find a diagram showing that 'State' is imported from Statemachines, so you have to look it in the corresponding chapter. Action State isn't in the document.